# Cannot instantiate simple BCL objects in Silverlight XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, types, resourcedictionary, base-class-library

If I declare the correct XML namespace, I can create/instantiate any of my own classes with a public and default constructor in a Silverlight XAML `ResourceDictionary`.

However, if I try that with any of the (non-UI) classes of the Base Class Library in the `System.*` namespaces, I get an error that the type cannot be found.

For example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BclObjectsInXamlDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:crypt="clr-namespace:System.Security.Cryptography;assembly=System.Core"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <crypt:AesManaged x:Key="AesManaged" />
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

gives me the error `The type 'AesManaged' was not found because 'clr-namespace:System.Security.Cryptography;assembly=System.Core' is an unknown namespace. [Line: 12 Position: 37]`.

I'm baffled because I thought it was easily possible. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and Silverlight 5. The `System.Core` assembly is linked correctly in my project (as it is by default). Can I declare the namespace in the XAML differently to make it work? If so, how?